# Delegation to another view controller is not working

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols, delegation

My sender class for delegation:

```
import UIKit

protocol tapDelgation:class {
    func tapConfirmed(message:String)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate:tapDelgation?

    @IBAction func deligateSenderAction(_ sender: Any) {
        var data = "hello world"
        print(data)
        self.delegate?.tapConfirmed(message: data)
    }
}
```

My reciever class:

```
import UIKit

class NextViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var vc:ViewController? =  ViewController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        vc?.delegate = self
    }
}

extension  NextViewController : tapDelgation {
    func tapConfirmed(message: String) {
        print(message)
    }
}
```

What is expected: A button on sender vc is pressed and from reciever vc a console print would be popped. But in vain, nothing happens. Does any one know why it is happening? If it is not possible then why?

Comment: Where does `NextViewController` ever display `vc`?

Comment: NextViewController comes after a page transition from ViewController

Comment: You need to show the code that does that.

Comment: do I need to use prepare??

Comment: It really depends on how exactly you are displaying "ViewController". I have a feeling that the "ViewController" instance you set the delegate on is not actually the ViewController instance that is being shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a memory management problem to me.

First problem: Creating a view controller with a default initializer like `ViewController()` is almost never the right thing to do. because it won't have any view contents.

You don't explain how your `NextViewController` and your `ViewController` get created and displayed.

It looks like `NextViewController` has a weak reference to `ViewController`, and `ViewController`'s delegate point is also weak (delegate references should almost always be weak.)

This line:

```
weak var vc:ViewController? =  ViewController()
```

Will cause `NextViewController` to create an instance of `ViewController` that isn't owned by anybody, so it will immediately be deallocated and the `vc` variable will go back to being nil. By the time you get to `NextViewController`'s viewDidLoad, `vc` will be nil, so the optional binding in the line `vc?.delegate = self` won't do anything.

`NextViewController`'s `vc` variable should almost certainly be a strong reference, not weak, but you don't show how `ViewController` ever gets displayed to the screen, so it isn't clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: I changed viewController to  SenderViewController but no luck
and Sender and receiver is connected via navigation controller. i.e. If i press a button on sender a recieve comes via push transition. my aim was to since it is triggered an IBAction then the second view controller  would implements the tap confirmed function.
thanks for your answer. Learned a lot :)

Comment: None of what you just said had anything to do with the memory management problem I describe. This line: `weak var vc:ViewController? =  ViewController()` Will never do anything useful. It will create a view controller (or whatever type of object) that will immediately get deallocated and discarded.

Answer (score 1):

```
weak var vc:ViewController? =  ViewController()
```

Remove weak if you don't set the vc somewhere else and any other instance doesn't keep a strong reference to it.

If there is another instance with a strong reference, please share the related code.

The answer from the https://stackoverflow.com/users/205185/duncan-c is totally correct unless there is any other code which affects the presentation of the `NextViewController` and reference to the `vc: ViewController`

> I changed viewController to SenderViewController but no luck and Sender and receiver is connected via navigation controller. i.e. If i press a button on sender a recieve comes via push transition. my aim was to since it is triggered an IBAction then the second view controller would implements the tap confirmed function. thanks for your answer. Learned a lot :)

Due to this comment, you need to implement `prepareForSegue()` method in your ViewController (original one) and set the vc property of the "next" view controller there instead of `=  ViewController()` in the "next" make the extension on the ViewController:

```
extension ViewController {
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let nextController = segue.destinationViewController as! NextViewController
        nextController.vc = self
    }
}
```

Explanation based on the comment:

You get a new instance of the NextViewController with the new instance of the ViewController instantiated on its init (instead of passing the original instance of ViewController to it). That's where you can ge a strange behaviour with delegation.

Answer (score 1):

weak var vc:ViewController? =  ViewController()
Remove weak for vc it will release the view controller memory after disappear